# Set / Reset Option in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, development-environment, settings

When we install Visual Studio 2008, we are asked about the settings for our environment like

visual c# / visual basic etc. When set, We may alter these options from

Tools --> Options --> Environment / TextEditor etc

My problem is, if we "mess" up these settings!!!! is there any way to restore defaults or particular Settings Template ??? as we can with many other Softwares

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Tools > Import and Export Settings` and select "Reset all settings".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a "Reset to Factory Defaults" option (but it's rather brute).

You find it under Tools | Import and Export Settings

Comment: I mean that it Resets everything - no choices.

Answer (score 1):

An additional note, if there is a possibility of needing to use other languages then you can select the appropiate project files from New > New Project and clicking on the language you wish to use.

For your needs though, Mickel's answer will work fine.

Comment: Tthat is the project template we do select, but by default the settings for the environment are kept according to VS settings in use ?. So If I have environment settings for VC#.Net, even if I start a new VB.NET  WindowsFormsApplication project from NewProject Template, My environment 
will persist with VC#.Net setting ? Is that what you mean ?

Comment: No it "should" revert to the environment that the template you have selected in the "New Project" dialogue uses.